# Fail to send the PATCH request to set the extended property in MAC outlook client

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi

I am developing an Office Add-in for MAC outlook client. I am trying to send the PATCH request to set the extended property in MAC outlook client but it does not work. There is no response after executing the code below.  The code snippet below works in MAC Safari browser and windows desktop/browser. Do you have any idea?

Note:Replace the XXXX with your email ID. The email ID can be retrieved by the outlook rest api sandbox. https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/ or via the Office.js Office.Context.Mailbox.Item.itemId https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5

```
        function setFlag() {
           var options = {
           isRest: true,
           };
           Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(options, cb);
        }

        function cb(asyncResult) {
           var token = asyncResult.value;
           setEmailFlagByToken(token);
        }
        function setEmailFlagByToken(accessToken) {
         var getMessageUrl = 'https://outlook.com/api/beta/me/messages/XXXX'
          $.ajax({
          url: getMessageUrl,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType:"application/json",
          type:'PATCH',
          data: "{'Flag':{'FlagStatus':'Flagged'}}",
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
          }).done(function(data){
             //Succeeded

          }).fail(function(error){
            // Handle error
          });   
        }


 Updated XML Manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>47837963-11df-469e-a84e-661070c8217c</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="OfficeAddIn" />
  <Description DefaultValue="OfficeAddIn"/>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://mailapppoc2.azurewebsites.net/AddInRead/Home/Home.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: The issue is fixed now by installing the Office Inside Fast and there is an installation bit updated in 9/2/2017 that fixes this issue. @deepak

Answer (score 0):

Rest token for making rest calls is supported in mac outlook client as part of 1.5 APIs. Please make sure you are using the latest outlook binary while making the request. In older binaries this support is not present. Earlier, it would only provide EWS token, which will enable you to make only ews requests. Insider fast program user get binaries which support this feature.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @deepak, my MAC outlook client version is 15.33(170409), do you think it will work?

Comment: No, 170409 doesn't have this support, you need to update the build. This feature has been release as part of Insider fast program for Outlook for mac. If you are not a part of insider fast program, kindly enroll.

Comment: @deepak, I joined the Insider fast program for Outlook for mac and download the updated installation bits, but this issue still existed. Current outlook client for MAC version is 15.37(170707), is this supposed to work?

Comment: yes, this should work. You should get rest token in 170707 build which can be used to make rest api call. What error you are getting?

Comment: @deepak, you are right.  the rest token can be get (it can also be get from 170409 actually), when send the PATCH request, the request cannot be sent out and we use the fiddle on MAC to watch requests but cannot see this request.

Comment: @deepak, btw are you available to send the PATCH request on your end using the latest MAC outlook client?

Comment: when you make the patch request, it is just a rest api call. You should be able to trace it in the Fiddler.

Comment: @deepak, in windows outlook client, the fiddle can watch the request in fiddle. In Mac outlook client, this request cannot be watched by fiddle and there is no trace log on that request. I suspect that the MAC outlook client blocks the request sending out and any more idea?

Comment: Only reason request can be blocked in mac client can be due to security reason. Cross site request require web address to be whitelisted by listing it in AppDomain section in the manifest file.

Comment: @deepak, thanks for your feedback. Actually the manifest file app domain section includes this link https://outlook.office.com, a quick question, are you available to reproduce the issue on your mac outlook client?

Comment: @ChrisBao yes, I can do that, kindly provide the manifest, i will give it a try.

Comment: @deepak, i have sent you the XML manifest file in the code section and by default it will send the PATCH request when load the add-in. Because the email ID might not be correct so you would get 403 access denied in windows desktop but in MAC outlook client you will not even see this request.